# How to find element with find_element_by_xpath multiple names selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm looking for a site where the name of the ID depends on some variables that I can't control.

So the ID can either be "sub_allGoods_4", "sub_allGoods_12" or whatever number:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sub_allGoods_4"]').text
```

Is there any way to use a * like to cover those cases?

```
find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sub_allGoods_**"]').text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `contains` function:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'sub_allGoods_')]
```

Comment: @user8459020 no problem, can you accept my reply as answer so the question doesn't remain open?